# Netbeans does not allow me to create multiple databases

Tags: java, netbeans, connection, derby

I have some projects opened in Netbeans and trying to connect two of them with `derby db` But Netbeans does not allow me to create more than one DBs. When I create second DB it destroy the previous one. Check out the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of derby db]

It override the new db and show only one (new one) under the JavaDB node But in the connection it shows both databases in my case `dictionaryDB`and `test`. So my question is how to create more than one DBs in netbeans?

Comment: For me works fine. Right click -> Create database in NeatBeans 8.2

Comment: I'm using `8.0.2`